# Are cmath exp() and log() functions always symmetrical?

Tags: c, math, cmath

Are cmath `exp()` and `log()` functions always symmetrical?

Ergo if I do

```
double x;
double y = exp(log(x));
assert(x == y);
```

will the assert ever fail, and in that case: under what circumstances? We can assume that `x` is a **rational number > 0**.

Comment: rounding error and representation error exists.

Comment: Note that **all** values that `x` could take are rational (except for NaN/inf).

Comment: Please ask your question about the guarantees of `log` and `exp` on different systems in another Stack Overflow post. Asking two questions in one post is problematic because respondents may answer the different questions in separate answers, and you can only mark one of them accepted. To address it briefly, current math libraries vary in quality and in the specific implementations, so results are not exactly the same from platform to platform.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, therefore the rational

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A floating-point `log` cannot be one-to-one.  It needs to be monotone increasing and satisfy `log(64) > 4.15` and `log(128) < 4.86`.  There are 2<sup>52</sup> `double`s between 64 and 128, but there are fewer than 2<sup>50</sup> `double`s between 4.15 and 4.86.  There are multiple `doubles` in that range with the same double-precision logarithm, so `exp(log(x)) == x` must fail for at least one of them.

Comment: It seems like a slight understatement to say 3•2**50 is “at least one”. :-)

Comment: With this reasoning, it seems to me that after a series of `exp(log())` the result could move a few bits from the original value, but symmetrical doubles should be pretty frequent and once you hit one further `exp(log())` calls will be exact. Valid?

Comment: @fickludd: I don't know.  I'd also guess that would be the case, but I don't think I can back up my intuition with anything rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

They are no more symmetrical than `*` and `/`. When dealing with floating point numbers there are rounding errors, so `x` and `y` may differ in the 15th (or so) digit.

Comment: are they less symmetrical that `*` and `/` then?