# c language symmetry in different cmath log() and exp() implementations?

Tags: c, math, cmath

Follow-up from the question [Are cmath exp() and log() functions always symmetrical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913277/are-cmath-exp-and-log-functions-always-symmetrical)

```
double x;
double y = exp(log(x));
assert(x == y);
```

Essentially, if one writes `log(x)` to disk and calculated `exp()` on another system - to what extent does the c language guarantee symmetry? Considering a long series of `exp(log())`, potentially on different systems, how far from the original `x` should one fear the result to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, I address the variation between systems, not the round-trip of `exp(log(x))`. As indicated in your other question, the round-trip result is generally not equal to the input, even with the best possible implementations of `exp` and `log`.

In practice, there is no guarantee of the accuracy of math library functions, and different providers use different algorithms and approximations, so results vary from platform to platform.

The best commercial libraries aim for sub-ULP accuracy, meaning that each result is within one unit in the last place (of the floating-point format) of the exact mathematical result. This is often not achieved for some of the more esoteric functions in the math library. Not all libraries aim for this. Even if two different libraries both guarantee sub-ULP accuracy, they will not always return identical results.

There is an academic project, [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) with the goal of providing correctly rounded implementations of the math library routines. A correctly rounded implementation returns the unique representable value that is closest to the exact mathematical result in the chosen rounding method (to nearest, toward zero, toward infinity, or toward –infinity). A correctly-rounded result is the most accurate result possible given the limitations of the floating-point format. crlibm-1.0beta3.pdf provides correctly-rounded implementations of `log` and `exp`, with proofs.

Because the correctly-rounded result is uniquely defined, two libraries with correctly-rounded implementations will return the same results as each other.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, floating-point operations like this (especially between different implementations of `log`, etc.) can never be guaranteed to have exact inverses. So my answer would be

1. there will definitely be some loss,
2. if you really care about how much, you should implement it and run a test, and
3. this really smells as if it's something you want to do, and there's a way to get around the problem, in which case I would ask: what are you trying to do, and why are you encountering this problem in the first place?

Comment: I'm implementing a lossy compression algorithm and want to make estimates on what precision loss can be expected from multiple uses.

Comment: @fickludd: This approach to compression will not work. Somebody else recently asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856407/algorithm-number-fractionning) regarding a vaguely similar approach. Essentially, you cannot compress data using math tricks. It does not take any fewer bits to store the logarithm of a number accurately enough to recover the number than it does to store the number directly. You might as well simply chop a few of the least significant bits of the number off (setting them to zero).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Since it's already deemed lossy, it's entirely possible for it to be useful (for instance, voice compression). This wouldn't be data compression - it would have to be applied to images, sound, etc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It turns out that a fixed point representation of a logged value offers a very attractive combination of precision and dynamic range for the type of values we are compressing =). Due to the fixed point we are throwing away the least significant bits anyway, so minor rounding error are not a problem as long as they don't add up.

Comment: @fickludd: A `double` is already in a logarithm-like state. A fast an easy way to reduce the number of bits required to represent it while retaining much of the accuracy is to convert it to `float`. If that is not the right size, then you can extract the exponent and significand with the `frexp` function and tailor them to your desired sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That assumes that he can use a log base 2, which may or may not be the case in some scientific applications (often it has to be `e`).

Comment: I wanted to use a custom unsigned two byte float originally, but handling the exponent and significand manually was just really tricky compared to throwing a `log()`.